# Hiding metadata at the beginning of an org-mode file

Tags: org-mode

I have a quite a bit of file-specific settings at the beggining for my org files. It looks as follows but there is many more lines:

```
#+STARTUP: overview
#+LINK: coderepo    x:/my/repo/%s
#+LINK: scriptsrepo x:/mysrcript/repo/
```

Is there a way to hide or fold them ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can put them at the end, maybe even in a heading that can be collapsed.

You might try a drawer:

```
:setup:
#+STARTUP: overview
#+LINK: coderepo    x:/my/repo/%s
#+LINK: scriptsrepo x:/mysrcript/repo/
:end:
```

For me, that is folded when I open the file.

Alternatively, I think you could put them in a separate setup.org file, and then include it as:

`#+include: setup.org`

Comment: The drawer works great! Thanks :).